# Input validation on int

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with the following code, when I enter a letter isdigit won't detect it and I get the error message "Nothing entered"

```
    int age;
    char buffer[100] = "";
    printf("Enter your age: ");
    fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
    age = atoi(buffer);
    printf("%d\n",age);


    if (age == NULL)
    {
        printf("Nothing entered\n");
    }

    else if (isdigit(age) == 0)
    {
        printf("Not a number\n");
    }

    else if (age <1 || age > 110)
    {
        printf("Out of range\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Thank you\n");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because of this: `age = atoi(buffer);` ? (`atoi` -> `ASCII To Int`)

Comment: you have to validate the input string before you check the content of age. look at the function definition of atoi and see what happens when it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
age = atoi(buffer);
printf("%d\n",age);


if (age == NULL)
{
    printf("Nothing entered\n");
}
```

Use

```
if ( sscanf(buffer, "%d", &age) != 1 )
{
    printf("Nothing entered\n");
}
else
{
    printf("%d entered\n", age);
}
```

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, please explain how I failed to use `sscanf` correctly.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, but I am using `sscanf` on the `buffer`. I am not using `scanf`.

Comment: Ah, alright. I was wrong then, sorry. (Over the years, I've seen such an enormous effort of bad advice demonstrating the wrong usage of `scanf()` that I've sort of developed a reflex to hunt for it.)

Answer (score 2):

`atoi` is the wrong function to use when you have untrusted/potentially erroneous input (i. e. almost always).

Use [`strtol()` (man page)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) instead, which allows for extensive error checking.

Also, **do check** the return value of `fgets()`.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    char *end;
    errno = 0;
    long n = strtol(buf, &end, 10);

    // check for errors
    if (n == 0 || n == LONG_MIN || n == LONG_MAX) {
        if (errno != 0) {
            printf("Erroneous input entered\n");
        } else {
            // process valid input
        }
    } else {
        // process valid input
    }
} else {
    printf("nothing was entered\n");
}
```

By the way, it doesn't make sense to compare an `int` with `NULL` (which is a pointer). If this doesn't trigger at least a compiler warning (better yet, a hard error), you need to boost your compiler warning level or change to a modern compiler.

Answer (score 0):

explanation of the behavior

```
atoi("x")
```

will return 0. This is becuase atoi stops on the first non digit

```
if (age == NULL)
```

is then true because NULL is defined as 0 (basically)

You should check buffer first and then do atoi

Comment: No, `atoi` is evil. Use `strtol` instead. https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/465515/tribal-knowledge-atoi-is-evil